# Admin, "manage categories" error. Source model "maattabel/categorie" not found for attribute "maattabel_categorie"

Tags: category, error

Suddenly `I went my admin panel and "manage categories" section has error. What should I do? I already refresh the cache and it still same`. All other admin page seems to be work fine including my frontend pages. Only the `"manage categories" section is not working`

It said,

```
There has been an error processing your request
Source model "maattabel/categorie" not found for attribute "maattabel_categorie" 

Trace:
#0 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(43632): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Source model "m...')
#1 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(201): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Abstract->getSource()
#2 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes.php(113): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_setFieldset(Array, Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset))
#3 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form.php(144): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tab_Attributes->_prepareForm()
#4 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(2591): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs.php(140): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(1966): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tabs->_prepareLayout()
#7 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(27977): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#8 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form.php(55): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'tabs')
#9 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(1966): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Edit_Form->_prepareLayout()
#10 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(27977): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#11 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container.php(82): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...')
#12 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(1966): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form_Container->_prepareLayout()
#13 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(27977): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout))
#14 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(27993): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#15 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(27760): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock('adminhtml/catal...', 'category.edit')
#16 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(27726): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#17 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(27731): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element))
#18 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(13941): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks()
#19 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(13866): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks()
#20 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(275): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout(NULL, true, true)
#21 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php(201): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->loadLayout()
#22 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(14015): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController->editAction()
#23 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(18399): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit')
#24 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(17933): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#25 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/includes/src/__default.php(20705): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#26 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#27 /homepages/27/d282225533/htdocs/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#28 {main}
```

Comment: Have you tried turning off compliation

Answer (score 0):

I hope `maattabel_categorie`  is `select or drop down attribute  of category type`.

Guess you `have creating this attribute using installer`.
As you have `creating dropdown and multi selection category attribute` ..so
you need `add source model for this attribute which is save it option and label`. 
 hope `maattabel/categorie means`(**youmodulde_Model_yourmodel**) did not define`option and labels`so this error .

resolve this and recompile again